# Intellij does not recognize lombok setters for Java Spring-Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, lombok

I am using IntelliJ on Ubuntu (runtime version 11.0.5) and currently I am building a `Spring-Boot` application. I am using the `lombok` plugin in order to generate `getters` and `setters` for my entity automatically. This is how my code looks like currently:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Document
public class Experts {

    @Id
    private final String id;


    private final String name;
    private final String desc;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private final Availability availability;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private final Language language;

}
```

Despite that when I try to use setters from another class, spring-boot doesnt not recognize them:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ExpertsServiceImpl implements ExpertsService{

    private final ExpertRepository repository;

    @Override
    public Experts updateExpert(Experts expert, String id) {
        Experts updated = findExpertById(id);
        if(updated == null) {
            throw new ExpertNotFoundException(id);
        }

        updated.setId(expert.getId()); // here is shows: Cannot resolve method 'setId' in 'Experts'
        repository.save(updated);
        return updated;
    }
```

On that note, I need to mention that same thing does not happen for getters. Lombok plug-in is activated and annotation processing is activated on IntelliJ:

[image]

Does anyone understand why this happens and how I could fix it? I appreciate any help you can provide

Comment: Does it compile outside of intelliJ, e.g. when calling mvn clean install from terminal?

Comment: I seem to recall having issues with lombok and java 11. Make sure to update your dependency to newest version of lombok. That fixed my issue. At the time I had to update to an experimental version, it should have been long since released.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your id is `final` lombok will only generate setters for fields that can be set.

Comment: damn mate I cant believe I didnt see this! thank you so much :)